# What do you call a number which is the same written backwards?

Tags: numbers, palindrome

What do you call a number which is the same written backwards?
Example 16061.

Answer (score 29):

> **Palindrome** /…/ **noun** a word, phrase, or sequence that reads the same backward as forward

*[This excerpt is from the Oxford Dictionary of English, third edition, which was edited by Angus Stevenson.](https://books.google.com/books?id=anecAQAAQBAJ&lpg=PP1&pg=PA1279#v=onepage&q&f=false)*

In the definition, a **sequence** refers to number chains. If you didn't want to be completely on the nose about it, you could work in the phrase **mirror imag**e to describe what you need as well.

Comment: Indeed, *palindrome* also describes musical sequences that are the same backwards. http://kottke.org/17/02/bachs-crab-canon-is-a-musical-palindrome

Comment: Although you have made it obvious that this is a quote from somewhere, please also provide the source in  plain text (and a link if possible), following [Stack Exchange policy](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/referencing).

Comment: I would generally use the adjective form myself.  *Palindrome* reads as referring a word to my mind, so *palindromic number* would be the equivalent number.

Comment: @Bobson One could as easily refer to a _numeric palindrome_. But if the context is clear ("Is the result of this calculation a palindrome?") then no adjective is needed to differentiate numeric palindromes from the ordinary alphabetic sort.

Comment: If you used the phrase "mirror image", I'd expect some sort of reflective symmetry: for example, "08080" is both a palindrome and a mirror image, while "12421" is a palindrome but not a mirror image.

Comment: @Mark I completely agree, but that's why I said you could work it in. While logically it doesn't make sense, as you mentioned, the underlying feeling you get is similar. You could describe it *like* a mirror image in an analogy.

Comment: Thanks for the input @Mark. Only 0's and 8's can be "written" backward and still be the same.

Answer (score 4):

The correct *mathematical term* is a **palindromic number** (or a **numerical palindrome**).

To quote [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Palindromic_number):

> A palindromic number or numeral palindrome is a number that remains
>   the same when its digits are reversed. Like 16461, for example, it is
>   "symmetrical". The term palindromic is derived from palindrome, which
>   refers to a word (such as rotor or racecar) whose spelling is
>   unchanged when its letters are reversed.

And for a more mathematical definition from [Wolfram](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PalindromicNumber.html):

> A palindromic number is a number (in some base b) that is the same
>   when written forwards or backwards, i.e., of the form a_1a_2...a_2a_1.
>   The first few palindromic numbers are therefore are 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5,
>   6, 7, 8, 9, 11, 22, 33, 44, 55, 66, 77, 88, 99, 101, 111, 121, ...
>   (OEIS A002113).

These in turn are used to form the derived terms **palindromic prime** and **strictly non-palindromic number**.